# Xcode: Setting UIControl background colour resets on orientation change

Tags: swift, xcode

In short, I made 'radio button' like buttons. When you press on button, its background gets set to dark green, and the others are set to light green.

However, when I rotate the device (I'm using the emulator) then the colour resets to light green - it's original colour as set up in the .xib file.

[image: Button selected]

[image: After the device is rotated]

Each of the green 'buttons' is a UIControl. I set the colour using

```
button.backgroundColor = unselectedColour
```

Comment: Do you mean 'UIButton'? Or is the "button" a UIView? Please show the code for the implementation of the "button"

Comment: No, its a UIView which I use as a button. In other words, I used the story board feature to drag and drop a UIView. Then I set its type as a UIControl. Then, I linked them as outlets to my class. I guess the closest to code I can give is: 

`@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIControl!`

Comment: I see, the approach I would take would be to subclass your "view/button", and in the subclass include an isSelected variable. You can then place a property observer on that variable. Another way would be to create the "views" as UIbuttons, because UIButtons can track states natively, then you could set the background colour depending on the state. My suggestion is try some code, if you don't come right post and will fix where you went wrong

Comment: Well that is all fine and well, the problem is that the colour resets when you change the phone's orientation?

Comment: Because when orientation changes it triggers a redraw of the layout. And if you are not tracking states, all your buttons would be "reset" hence you loose the background change. But if you are tracking state during the redraw you would set the background color to the corresponding state

Comment: Ah, ok! I'll have a look at the property observers and see what I can do! Thank you for the help! Will post the solution as soon as I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

So, like Alexander suggested, I managed to get this working using a property observer.

Like mentioned above, I have 3 buttons. I also have an enum to help remember which button has been selected (eg. none, button1, button2, button3). I keep a variable to keep track of this enum, with the property observer like so:

```
/** Remember the last trailer selection made. */
var lastSelection: MyEnum = .none {
   willSet {
       setButtonColours(selection: newValue)
   }

   didSet {
   }
}
```

Each button's action sets the lastSelection variable, which then triggers this. Finally, I had to add this little bit of code to make sure that the redraw happens after the orientation change:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    setButtonColours(selection: lastSelection)
}
```

I don't know if this is the BEST solution (as I'm a noob), but it works! Thank you again Alexander for the help!